# dplyr selecting observations with filter

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I select Giovanni Bianchi and Luca Rossi from the dataset below using dplyr?

```
NAME          SURNAME   COLOR   ...
Giovanni      Rossi     Red 
Giovanni      Bianchi   Red 
Giovanni      Bianchi   Blue 
Luca          Rossi     Blue
Luca          Rossi     Red
Giovanni      Rossi     Red
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `paste` to create the full name and `filter` to subset on that new variable

```
library(dplyr)

filter(d,paste(NAME,SURNAME) %in% c("Giovanni Bianchi","Luca Rossi"))

      NAME SURNAME COLOR
1 Giovanni Bianchi   Red
2 Giovanni Bianchi  Blue
3     Luca   Rossi  Blue
4     Luca   Rossi   Red
```

Data

```
d <- read.table(text="
NAME          SURNAME   COLOR
Giovanni      Rossi     Red 
Giovanni      Bianchi   Red 
Giovanni      Bianchi   Blue 
Luca          Rossi     Blue
Luca          Rossi     Red
Giovanni      Rossi     Red ",head=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```